# Resources on using annotations in Java/Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, annotations

There are two methods of using Spring (Annotations/XML). In XML we specify everything in XML files. In annotations we use commands like `<context:component-scan base-package="com.xyz" />` `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` etc. Thus in annotations there is complete scan of packages to identify dependencies etc. So being a beginner i want to know its overall effect on our application.

**EDIT**
Please don't make a fight over initialization of Spring. Its a general question. You can take an example of Hibernate also. Struts or anything else.

Missed out Java Config. So about that too.

Comment: "There are two methods of using Spring (Annotations/XML)" -> actually there are 3 - you can also use Java to configure up your container as of Spring 3.0.

Comment: `XML-based` versus `Annotation-based` configuration in Spring are two sides of a coin up for debate! XML tends to get messy and unwieldy as the application grows bigger. Obviously, it cannot be entirely avoided as it is the basis for instantiating a Spring context. That being said, XML still makes for a readable application as a whole, while annotations make the source more readable. Effectively, both are equivalent in terms of "effect" on an application.

Comment: Web User is incorrect about xml configuration "[not being] entirely avoided"; you can instantiate a spring context with no XML. See for example http://www.thebinaryidiot.com/archives/2012/04/05/simple-spring-mvc-part-1/

Comment: @WebUser You can create an application context entirely based on Java configuration, see the [Java-based container configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java) in the Spring reference documentation.

Comment: @matsev and rhollencamp, you are both right. I recently read about it, and forgot to include. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge a good mix up of both patterns will lead to a good application.

XML - as it grows become more verbose and tough to maintain.

Annotations - will make the code more easier to read. Well you can maintain the scanning strictly at the package levels by configuring in the xml so it should not affect your application.

Since the xml is a mandatory thing for initial spring instantiations you cannot avoid that. So ideally a mix up will be a great thing.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with raddykrish.

I also believe that the mix of annotation and xml configurations is the best practice.

You can divide your Spring configuration in two categories.

1. The one time configurations you need to do for using any Spring module or other third party tools to integrate with Spring.
2. The beans you need to create to make them inject.

Configurations for using Spring Security, locale resolver, view resolver etc. falls under the first category. You should better put them in an xml for better management of your configurations.

And the beans for the controllers, services, dao etc. of your application should be annotated and make them scan by Spring. Because its very tedious process in a big application to make xml bean for each of them separately. It looks ugly and very difficult to manage.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.